# Get four values with only one textbox and print them on different lines

Tags: javascript, html, developer-tools

How can I get four values from user using only one textbox and print these four values on different lines?

```
function getData(){
    var x,i;
    var text=" ";
    for(i=0;i<=3;i++)
    {
        text=document.getElementById("inp").value;
    }
    document.getElementById("valu").innerHTML=text;
    
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] (you get a badge!), have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) I also recommend Jon Skeet's [Writing the Perfect Question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) and [Question Checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Please make your title match your question. Right now it looks like an advertisement for a job.

Answer (score 1):

> How can I get four values from user using only one textbox...

You have two choices if you absolutely **must** use only one textbox:

1. Have the user enter one value at a time and press a button (or similar) to tell you they're done with that value. Then you'd store the value and clear the box so they can type the next one. When they've given you four, do you work.
2. Have them enter the values with some kind of delimiter (a space, a comma, etc.), then split the text you get from the box on that delimiter.

> ...and print these four values on different lines?

Either have four blank elements you put the text in (the same way you've put text in one element in the code in your question, but I'd use `textContent`, not `innerHTML`), or add them dynamically (see [`createElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement), [`appendChild`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild), and [similar](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model)).

Comment: I've intentionally **not** written the code for this because it seems like this may well be for a class or similar, and so it seems more appropriate to explain how rather than doing the work for you.

Comment: yes the first choice is right can you share code how to do this and after print these value and save in variable for furtur use